# Dojo, setAttribute with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dojo, setattribute

I'm working on a web application that I didn't make myself and it has been done using Dojo and specially Dijit. 
The part which I'm struggling with is about a form that gets changed depending on radio buttons.
Therefore, I'm using `dijit.byId('id').setAttribute('disabled',true);` to disabled a field and this works on FF but not with IE8. Although, it works but not directly when I check the radio button, I have to do one more action (like clicking in a random area on the page) and the action is applied. I tried with stuff like: `document.getElementById('id').disabled=true;` but it doesn't work correctly either.

Would you please have any suggestion?
Thank you.

Comment: Couple of questions:  What version of Dojo is it?  Where (in which functions) have you tried to call your disable code?

Comment: Just so you know, the two "answers" that you posted are not answers.  Instead of posting an "answer" that is an additional question, you can either edit your original question or ask another question.  In this case, your first question about setting attribute has been answered.  Your next series of "answers" should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: I'm not going to edit my first question. It's going to be such a mess between my first one, the answers, the other questions and the new answers. I can't either answer as a comment since my codes won't be displayed as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo Widgets have a convention to set attributes using the set method.

```
dijit.byId('id').set('disabled',true);
```

This convention will call the `_setDisabledAttr` method on the widget which will take care of making itself disabled.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/_WidgetBase.html#attributes

Comment: This solution also works but it doesn't solve my problem. I click on my radio button that directly changes the status of the fields in FF but I need a second click (wherever) to see the changes in IE. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We had nearly the same Problem as you do.

Try dijit.registry to get or set attributes for disabled or enabled.

We had the problem with a query that tested whether one or the other radio button was active. Then another record should be read at a time.
Unfortunately this did not work with dojo.byId so we looked for a solution and found it as described above in dijit.registry.

Here's the link:http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/registry.html#dijit-registry

Hope it might help you.

Regards, Miriam

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it if I run into this issue again but so far, my problem has been solved by an "onclick" instead of "onchange".